# Error when trying to run delayed_job in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, background-process, activesupport

I am using delayed_job to send emails, everything works fine under development when starting the process using:

```
jobs:work
```

The problem comes on my shared host, under production, when I try and start the process using the "delayed_job" script (as detailed [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job))

```
script/delayed_job start staging
```

gives me the following error

```
/home/blog/applications/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require': no such file to load -- delayed/command (LoadError)
    from /home/blog/applications/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require'
    from /home/blog/applications/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/blog/applications/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:636:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/blog/applications/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/blog/applications/staging/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require'
    from script/delayed_job:4
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this please?

I am using Rails 3.1 on Ruby 1.8.7, with Phusion Passenger.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Capistrano for these kind of things.
Then you could simply put this in your deploy.rb file (or Capfile):

```
require 'delayed/recipes'

after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start"
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop"
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
```

Certainly made it a lot easier for me =)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Icid, I have already tried your suggestion, and get exactly the same error :-(

Comment: Have you tried bundling it straight from the git repo? https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job